# Build native-lib_arm64-v8a : error: no matching function for call to 'av_rescale_q_rnd'

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile my native-lib.cpp, but I keep getting this error. The issue here is for the parameter

```
pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
        pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
        pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
```

the error which i got

```
> Task :app:externalNativeBuildRelease
Build native-lib_armeabi-v7a
ninja: Entering directory `\app\.cxx\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a'
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library \app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a\libnative-lib.so
Build native-lib_arm64-v8a
ninja: Entering directory `\app\.cxx\cmake\release\arm64-v8a'
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o 
\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android23 --gcc-toolchain=/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot  -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS -I/app/src/main/libs/arm64-v8a/include -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -frtti -fexceptions -O2 -DNDEBUG  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles\native-lib.dir\native-lib.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o -c /app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:716:19: error: no matching function for call to 'av_rescale_q_rnd'
        pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (enum AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/app/src/main/libs/arm64-v8a/include\libavutil/mathematics.h:160:9: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'AVRational *' to 'AVRational' for 2nd argument; dereference the argument with *
int64_t av_rescale_q_rnd(int64_t a, AVRational bq, AVRational cq,
        ^
/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:717:19: error: no matching function for call to 'av_rescale_q_rnd'
        pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (enum AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/app/src/main/libs/arm64-v8a/include\libavutil/mathematics.h:160:9: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'AVRational *' to 'AVRational' for 2nd argument; dereference the argument with *
int64_t av_rescale_q_rnd(int64_t a, AVRational bq, AVRational cq,
        ^
/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:718:24: error: no matching function for call to 'av_rescale_q'
        pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/app/src/main/libs/arm64-v8a/include\libavutil/mathematics.h:151:9: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'AVRational *' to 'AVRational' for 2nd argument; dereference the argument with *
int64_t av_rescale_q(int64_t a, AVRational bq, AVRational cq) av_const;
        ^
3 errors generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

> Task :app:externalNativeBuildRelease FAILED
```

from above error i think it throws only for arm64-v8 itseems

```
app\src\main\libs\arm64-v8a\include\libavutil\mathematics.h:151:9: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'AVRational *' to 'AVRational' for 2nd argument; dereference the argument with *
```

[image]

As it is an ffmpeg example code block and i didnt change anything. Android Studio throws error only when i try to generate signed apk and i can run this in my Android 6 device without error.

I tried replacing `in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base` into `*in_stream->time_base, *out_stream->time_base` it throws other type of error

```
app\src\main\cpp\native-lib.cpp:716:45: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('AVRational' invalid)
```

Comment: I don't see how you can get this error; the `time_base` field of an `AVStream` struct is already a AVRational. Which version of ffmpeg is this?

Comment: Íts 'ffmpeg-snapshot'. Downloaded a month ago

Comment: So what is the type of that field in your checkout?

Comment: `AVRational *time_base;(from main\libs\arm64-v8a\include\libavformat\avformat.h)` and `AVStream *in_stream, *out_stream;(from native-lib.cpp)`

Comment: That field has been a plain AVRational (not a pointer) for [17 years](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blame/master/libavformat/avformat.h#L896). Looks like you accidentally changed it. Please make sure your ffmpeg checkout is pristine OR tell us what else you changed.

Comment: yes you are right,i checked my ffmpeg build files and ffmpeg github source files 
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/avformat.h#L896
its `AVRational time_base` only. i think i may have accidentally changed with android studio Intentions dialog in somepoint of time.Thanks for your time!